# Python3: list comprehensions and stack frames

Tags: python, list-comprehension, stack-frame

Consider this function:

```
def quux():
    i = 42 
    print([i for x in [1]])
```

Result: [42]

Therefore, I assume that local vars are visible in list comprehensions.

Now consider this:

```
def foo():
    return currentframe().f_back.f_locals["i"]

def quux():
    i = 42 
    print([foo() for x in [1]])
```

Result in:

> KeyError: 'i'

Inspecting the stack frames, it turns out there's an additional stack inserted in-between frames for quux and foo:

```
{'x': 1, '.0': <tuple_iterator object at 0x7f59eb94c860>}
```

Ok, fair enough. What I am puzzled about though is why does the first example see `i`. If there's an additional stack frame it should not be visible, no?

And on more practical grounds, how can I get stack frame of calling function, irrespective of whether my function was called from without or from within a list comprehension, or for that matter, from within multiple nested list comprehensions?

Comment: the main question is: what are you trying to achieve/why do you need that? IMO messing with frames is not a good idea since it's a kind of magic

Comment: change  `print([foo() for x in [1]])` to     `print([foo(i) for x in [1]])`  and  `def foo():
    return currentframe().f_back.f_locals["i"]` to `def foo(i):
    return currentframe().f_back.f_locals[i]`

Comment: Azat: Trying to do something like JavaScript template literals (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

But irrespective whether it's a good idea or not, how come that "i" in the first example is visible given that there's an interleaved stack frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good observation (irrespective of its usefulness :) ). The best way to answer your question is to see for yourself: dump the disassembly (using `dis.dis(quux)` in two versions). You will notice the important difference in two version is the closure being loaded in the first version. This is because you referred to the variable i in the list comprehension object and by doing so you have made i a part of the closure and the list comp have access to it. In the second case no such things so you get that error.

For the second part, now that you understand it, probably you will like to re-phrase it?

Comment: Here's tthe use case: `def foo: print(eval("i", currentframe().f_back.f_locals, currentframe().f_back.f_globals))`. This works fine when foo() is called if it's called in a simple way. It breaks when it's called from within a list comprehension. Is there a way to make it work in both cases?

Comment: You will simply need to refer to `i` in your list comp to make it part of the closure. You can simply make `foo` as function of `i` and refer to `foo` in the list comp as `foo(i)`. Closure will do the rest of the magic!

Comment: Ok, that doesn't solve my problem (I don't know the list of variables I'll need in advance) but it explains why it may not be possible. Thanks!

Comment: If you put a fresh question based on this exactly what you are solving , that may help. To get `i` it either has to be local (with or without a closure) or global. If you do not want `foo` to be a function of `i`, you can simply have `print([(foo(),i) for x in [1]])` . This makes a reference to `i` and will be part of the locals of the list comp, accessible from `foo` using `.f_back.f_locals`.

Comment: I was trying to make template literals (an in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). The variable appears only as part of the input string (e.g. template_literal("Value of i is ${i}")), so you can't really insert it into the closure unless you want to parse the expression in ${} at runtime, determine the variables it contains etc.

Comment: Apologies, but it seems the closest to template literals in python is the new `f` formatting. like below `variable = 42\nprint(f"variable is {variable}")`. Not sure why we need to look through stack frames. Suggest put a fresh question with your use case so that others can have a go at it. Thx vm.

Answer (score 1):

What gives the visibility of a variable is its *scope*, not the possible frames. Python local variables have function scope, so in first example the `i` variable is visible from any line inside the `quux` function.

Frames are just a CPython implementation detail. From the standard library documentation for the `inspect` module:

> inspect.currentframe() 
>   Return the frame object for the caller’s stack frame.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This function relies on Python stack frame support in the interpreter, which isn’t guaranteed to exist in all implementations of Python. If running in an implementation without Python stack frame support this function returns None.

When an implementation uses Python stack frame support, the implementation will have frames for explicit function calls, and may add interleaving frames for internal usage, here for the list comprehension, but there may be other use cases.

So here you have 2 possible choices:

- pragmatic: you have found that in that use case there is exactly one interleaving frame, so you can just skip it:

  ```
  def foo():
      return currentframe().f_back.f_back.f_locals["i"]
  ```
- documentation wise:

  You know that an outer frame will contain an `i` local variable. Just scan the outer frames for the first one that contains it:

  ```
  def foo():
      for f in getouterframes(currentframe()):
          if 'i' in f.frame.f_locals:
              return f.frame.f_locals['i']
      return None
  ```